# Using struct variables in functions - Conflicting types

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to pass struct variables to a function, but I receive:

```
error: conflicting types for 'referenzspannung'
void referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In my `measure.h` I wrote the prototype:

```
void referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess);
```

and in the `measure.c` there is the struct+function:

```
struct ADMESSUNG {
    unsigned long Coderef;
    double Uref;
    double Stcal;
    double Offset;
    unsigned long Temperaturcode;
    double Temperaturavin;
    double RTD;
    double R;
    double Tempwert;
    unsigned long Phcode;
    double Phavin;
    double Stprobe;
    double PHWert;
};
struct ADMESSUNG mess;
void referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess) {
    AD7793_SetIntReference(AD7793_REFSEL_INT);
    AD7793_SetExcitDirection(AD7793_DIR_IEXC1_IOUT2_IEXC2_IOUT1);
    AD7793_SetExcitCurrent(AD7793_EN_IXCEN_210uA);
    AD7793_SetChannel(AD7793_CH_AIN3P_AIN3M);
    mess->Coderef = AD7793_ContinuousReadAvg(50);
    mess->Uref = ((mess->Coderef / 8388608) - 1) * 1.17; // code in voltage
}
```

In my `main.c` I call the function then:

```
referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess);
```

Does anyone see a mistake? I think I did everything in the right order and I have the syntax from multiple websites.

Comment: `referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess);` is not how to call a function, it looks more like a function *declaration*, but only without the return type.

Comment: You do not call it. You define it.

Comment: how do I call it then? I want it to calculate Uref for the other functions

Comment: Quite honestly, just about any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you how to call a function. I even bet that you have called many functions before (like `scanf` and `printf` for example) without any problems.

Comment: `referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess);` -> `referenzspannung(&mess);`

Comment: Your favourite C beginner-level book will demonstrate how to call functions in the chapter "functions"...

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition `struct ADMESSUNG {...}` to your .h file.

The compiler makes assumptions about what the struct looks like when it encounters `void referenzspannung(struct ADMESSUNG *mess);` with out knowing what the struct looks like.

The compiler would warn you about these assumptions. In gcc use `-Wall` to get all warnings.

The instance declaration `struct ADMESSUNG mess;` needs to be in the main.c to be visible where it is referenced or should be in the .h with an `extern` modifier.

The function call should reference the struct instance `referenzspannung(&mess);` as it is not a pointer.

Comment: It is enough to put a forward declaration 'struct ADMESSUNG' to the header before declarations of the functions.

Comment: I think he is good just w `struct ADMESSUNG ` in .h file.

Comment: OK so I did check this out and I was right you are OK w putting only `struct ASDMESSUNG;` in header file and leaving rest in source file.